# Programatically configuring Meltano

Tags: meltano, elt

I am considering using Meltano as the EL tool in an application that allows users to configure their data sources so they are replicated to a data lake. For that, it would be necessary to configure Meltano extractors and loaders programatically based on the user request. The application configuring them would not be running on the same server as Meltano.

Is there a way to do this? Reading the documentation, I've seen that Meltano is configured by a CLI, or directly editing the extractors' and loaders' YAML files. There doesn't seem to be an API or anything like that (except for running jobs, where you have Airflow or Dagster integrations). Should my application edit YAML files?

Comment: Your application could build YAML files on the fly and pass those to a subprocess that calls `meltano run`.